# DQL on ManyToMany relationship : multiple where parameters

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have 2 entities with a relation ManyToMany

```
class User{
    /**
     * Owning Side
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Aire\AppBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="projectFollowed")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="project_followed",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/
    private $projectFollowed;
}

class Project{
    /**
     * Inverse Side
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="projectFollowed")
     **/
    private $projectFollowed;
}
```

I need to check in my project_followed table if there is already a user assigned to this project.

```
$dql = '
        SELECT user
        FROM Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User user
        INNER JOIN user.projectFollowed project_followed
        WHERE project_followed.project_id = :project_id
        AND project_followed.user_id = :user_id
    ';

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query = $em
        ->createQuery( $dql )
        ->setParameter( 'project_id', $project_id )
        ->setParameter( 'user_id', $user_id )
        ;
```

It seems my DQL is not correct :

> Class AppBundle\Entity\Project has no field or association named project_id

So if i change

```
WHERE project_followed.project_id = :project_id
```

to

```
WHERE project_followed.id = :project_id
```

It is working but how can i make the relation with the user id?

The reason of this is because i need to check if there is no duplicate entries.

Comment: DQL uses your entity properties, not database column names.  Change your query to select from project.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't change anything to the returned error. The thing is that the relation ManyToMany create a relation table with the column user_id (that refer to the id of the class user) and project_id (that refer to the id of the class project). So it is slightly more complicate that just using the properties.

Comment: Nope.  Forget about database tables when using doctrine orm.  There is no such thing as a project_followed at the object level when using a ManyToMany relation between User and Project.  Read an example from the documentation.  Entity User should have an array property called projects and entity Project should have an array property called users.  The join table is invisible to dql.

Comment: For now i use an alternative solution : catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException $e){} I don't know which one is better. It still pretty confusing to me despite i well understood i should forget about database. Thank you for your help.